# Can we use performance.mark() in a new window or a tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I'm trying to use UserTiming API to capture the performance time metrics and it seems like I'm unable to measure the time between two marks if the second mark opens on a new window or a tab. To be more precise, I have a performance.mark('mark1') onEnter that opens a new window or a tab and the performance.mark('mark2')

Please assist. Any suggestions or comments are much appreciated!

Comment: Opening a new window or tab creates a completely independent JavaScript environment.

Comment: Well, you mean it's not possible to do measure the metrics if I open in a new tab unless use some sessionStorage or localStorage